# Iron Ore and experience

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you mine Iron Ore and instead of smelting it, just repeatedly place and mine the block, would that give me more experience?

Comment: you don't get XP from mining Iron, only smelting it.

Comment: Now, if you have the fuel, you can smelt cobble into stone, then place and break it and smelt it again....rinse and repeat....but for a measly .1xp, not really worth my time.

Answer (score 7):

No, you have never been able to get XP from mining iron ore itself.

For ores that don't drop into items (iron, gold, or any ores when using silk-touch), you only get the XP when you smelt the ores and take the smelted items out of the furnace.